# is it possible to set expire time when using opsForValue to increment value in spring boot

Tags: redis

Now I am using this code to increment a value in spring boot :

```
 String loginFailedKey = "admin-login-failed:" + request.getPhone();
        Object loginFailedCount = loginFailedTemplate.opsForValue().get(loginFailedKey);
        if (loginFailedCount != null && Integer.valueOf(loginFailedCount.toString()) > 3) {
            throw PostException.REACH_MAX_RETRIES_EXCEPTION;
        }
        List<Users> users = userService.list(request);
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(users)) {
            loginFailedTemplate.opsForValue().increment(loginFailedKey, 1);
            throw PostException.LOGIN_INFO_NOT_MATCH_EXCEPTION;
        }
```

is it possible to set an expire time when increment the key? If a new increment command happen, update the expire time. I read the docs and did not found the implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way in Spring Boot.

One of the *indirect* ways is to use LUA srcipt.

For example:

```
RedisScript script = RedisScript.of(
        "local i = redis.call('INCRBY', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])"
        + " redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], ARGV[2])"
        + " return i");

redisTemplate.execute(script, key, String.valueOf(increment),
        String.valueOf(expiration));
```